# Probability of Events A and B

Tags: probability

> Suppose $P(\overline{A})=0.3, P(B)=0.4, P(A\overline{B})=0.5,$ find the probability of $P(B|A\cup\overline{B}).$

I've tried doing this question on my own and so far I have $P(B|A\cup\overline{B})= \frac{P(B\cap(A\cup\overline{B}))}{P(A\cup\overline{B})}$ and $ P(A\cup\overline{B}) = 0.7+0.6-0.5 = 0.8$ but I don't know how to calculate $P(B\cap(A\cup\overline{B}))$. Is there any formula that I can use? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P(B|A \cup \bar B)=P(B|A)$. (Since $B$ and $\bar B$ are mutually exclusive).

Or, to use your intermediate result, $P(B\cap(A\cup\overline{B}))=P((B\cap A)\cup(B \cap \bar B))=P(B\cap A)$ since $(B \cap \bar B)=\emptyset$. (The first equality is just using the distributive law).

Now $P(B\cap A)=P(A)-P(A \cap \bar B)=0.7-0.5$

I'm sure you can take it from here.